# Deep learning with data from simulations

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

While reading the great [book by F. Chollet](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-python), I'm experimenting with Keras / Tensorflow, on a simple `Sequential` model that I train on simulated images, which come from a physical analytical model.

Having full control of the simulations, I wrote a `generator` which produces an infinite stream of data and label batches, which I use with `fit_generator` in Keras. The data so generated are never identical, plus I can add some random noise to each image.

Now I'm wondering: is it a problem if the model never sees the same input data from one epoch to the next? 
Can I assume my problems in getting the loss down are not due to the fact that the data are "infinite" (so I only have to concentrate on hyper parameters tuning)? 
Please feel free if you have any advice for dealing with DL on simulated data.

Comment: might be a better fit on [DS](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A well trained network will pick up on patterns in the data, prioritizing new data over old. If your data comes from a constant distribution this doesn't matter, but if that distribution is changing over time it should adapt (slowly) to the more recent distribution.

The fact that the data is never identical does not matter. Most trained networks use some form of data augmentation (e.g. for image processsing, it is common for images to be randomly cropped, rotated, resized, and have color manipulations applied etc, so each example is never identical even if it comes from the same base image).